# Problema con Lectura de archivos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo algunas dudas referente al tema de trabajar con ficheros en python ya que estoy empezando en este tema. Es que tengo que hacer un programa que lea líneas de números separadas por **`":"`** de un fichero **`.txt`** en este caso de **`comunicaciones.txt`** que tiene este contenido: (Tiene bastante más pero por no hacer un post demasiado grande)

```
Tarifa 3

08:48:45

10:30:54

07:33:11

23:58:10

05:10:18

14:52:43

05:25:47

06:10:05

03:03:25

08:07:30
```

Y luego muestre por pantalla Tarifa 0 y la primera línea de números en este caso: `08:48:45`
dónde 08 son las horas 48 los minutos 45 los segundos y con una función previamente hecha calcular su precio en base a una tarifa por segundo (royo telefonía).

**ESTO ES LO QUE LLEVO DE CÓDIGO:**

```
lista=[]

def pasar_a_segundos(horas,minutos,segundos):
    pasarhoras=horas*3600
    pasarminutos=minutos*60
    segundos=pasarhoras+pasarminutos+segundos
    return segundos


def calcular_coste(calculoseg,tarifa):
    precio=calculoseg*tarifa
    return precio


def convertir_a_euros(precio):
    eurofinal=round(precio/100,2)
    return eurofinal



abrir=open("comunicaciones.txt","r")
type(abrir)

with open("comunicaciones.txt","r") as fichero:
    primera=True
    for linea in fichero:
        if primera:

        else:
            linea=linea.split(":")
            horas=int(lista[0])
            minutos=int(lista[1])
            segundos=int(lista[2])

print(listalineas)
print(len(listalineas))
```

Doy por hecho que hay que separar los valores de los `":"` pero luego no soy capaz de pasar esos valores a segundos para luego hacer el cálculo de precio de todos los segundos en `€`.

Lo siento si me explico mal pero es bastante complicado, os dejo el enunciado del problema para asegurar la ayuda.

> Realiza un programa que te informe de cuanto vale cada comunicación y el total de dinero de todas las comunicaciones. En esta ocasión los datos de la duración de las comunicaciones y la tarifa por segundos se encuentran en este fichero donde en la primera línea te encuentras la tarifa, y en las restantes la duración de cada una de las comunicaciones expresadas en horas, minutos y segundos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es verificar que despues de separar hay 3 elementos y estos sean digitos, despues recien debes desempaquetarlos y convertirlos a enteros para hacer las operaciones necesarias:

```
with open("comunicaciones.txt","r") as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        linea=linea.strip().split(":")
        if len(linea) == 3 and all(c.isdigit() for c in linea):
            hora, minuto, segundo = map(int, linea)
            segundos = pasar_a_segundos(hora, minuto, segundo)
            print(segundos)
```